# Möbius Inversion for Infinite series

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion

The Möbius Inversion for an infinite series(assuming absolute convergence) is given by, if 
\begin{equation}
b(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a(kn) \iff a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(k)\, b(kn)
\end{equation}
The proof is given as 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(k)\, \sum_{d=1}^\infty a(dkn) = \sum_{N=1}^\infty a(Nn)\, \sum_{k|N}\mu(k) = a(n)
\end{equation}

My question is how we use above if we have a series of the type
\begin{equation}
b(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a(kn)\,x^k 
\end{equation}
Can we say that
\begin{equation}
b(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a(kn)\,x^k \iff a(n)x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(k)\, b(kn) \qquad \qquad ? 
\end{equation}
I think I am wrong but have no idea how to get Möbius Inversion of the above type series.?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: No. But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) \sum_{k=1}^\infty a(kn) x^{kn} = ?$

Comment: Also with $b(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a(kn) x^k$ then $a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k b(nk)$ where $y_k$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $x^k$ ie. $\sum_{d | k} y_d x^{k/d} = 1_{k = 1}$